# Why does NodeJs req.get('host') result to localhost:3000 on digital ocean instead of my actual domain name

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean, pm2, request-headers

I have a droplet on digital ocean. Everything works fine and is configured properly. However, I have nodeJs running on this droplet.
This code req.get('host') outputs localhost:3000 instead of my domain name.
Please how do i fix this, what file do i need to make this change.

Comment: How do you make the request?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i simply make the get request via the browser or even postman.

Comment: `rew.get('host')` returns the host of the requester. If you send the request from `localhost` it will be ,`localhost`

Comment: when this nodeJs code runs on any other server, req.get('host') returns the domain name of that server, i feel something is not right on my digital ocean server.

Comment: It's not related to where the server runs. This is read from the http header of the request.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski how come every other server outputs its domain, except this particular one i'm using

Comment: What do you mean by *every other server*? Did you host the same code on different servers? Do the other servers serve websites? I guess that this server is a rest API without any html severed and the others serve html.

Comment: Yes i tested this same code on heroku and it outputs the domain of the heroku server, but on my digital ocean droplet, it outputs localhost:3000. 
Maybe i should even tell you what i want, i want a code that basically tells me the domain name of my current server with nodejs

Comment: You were right lol. Seems like digital ocean is proxying your requests.

Comment: Yes lols. Let me write to them. I found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the docs of expressJs.
I observed digital ocean is proxying my requests, therefore adding the hostname in x-forwarded-host header property.

http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.host

When the trust proxy setting does not evaluate to false, this property will instead get the value from the X-Forwarded-Host header field. This header can be set by the client or by the proxy.

If there is more than one X-Forwarded-Host header in the request, the value of the first header is used. This includes a single header with comma-separated values, in which the first value is used.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to your dns settings in digital ocean panel
they explain it [here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/dns/how-to/manage-records/)

```
WILL DIRECT TO, which can be set to: 
A DigitalOcean Droplet or Load Balancer by typing its name and selecting it from the menu.
```

Its possible that you use `WILL DIRECT TO` option and because it's redirected the hostname is `localhost`

Comment: Yes this was my discovery after soo much research. Thanks